# Open linear subspace of a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Does there exist any open linear (vector) subspace of a Hilbert space? I could not think of any example.

Actually, I was reading the book by Simmons, there almost in every theorem it assumed that "If M is a closed linear subspace".It seemed natural to me to think about subspaces which are not closed. I have an got an example which is not closed:
Take the Hilbert space **H = L^[0,1], with L^2 norm** and the subspace **set of all polynomials**, it is not closed because it's closure is **H** and not open can be found here [Set of all polynomials on [0, 1/2] is not open in C[0, 1/2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/385464/428326). Then I asked myself an example of  to think of an open set. But I could lead myself nowhere, as I am not familiar with infinite dimensional vector space. Not closed does not necessarily mean open.

Comment: Linear span of a ball = ?

Comment: @metamorphy If you take a ball in R^n, and take an open ball around a point. then it contains at n linearly independent vectors, span of those vectors give you whole R^n. We know whole space is an open set but my point was in asking a proper subspace. Or what else you wanted to say?

Comment: I'm telling you that there's no proper subspace. A nonempty open set contains some ball, the linear span of which is the whole space (this is true for any dimensions, including infinite).

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my close vote; I misread the question.

Comment: Nice question. Glad you didn't give up on it. :) +1.

Comment: @metamorphy I got the answer. I will write it and upload. thanks for your hint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An example of non-closed subspace of a Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057526/an-example-of-non-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space)

Comment: @Lord_Farin, sorry, I didn't understand, what you wanted to say.

Comment: @BappaGhosh That this question is already answered before on Maths.SE, as you can see by following the link. Making this link formal (by closing as a *duplicate*) helps to avoid double efforts on the site.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, I checked before I put the question. My question is, " Is there any open subspace of a Hilbert ." But that question reads non closed subspace of a Hilbert space. Now Non closed subspace doesn't mean open.

Comment: @BappaGhosh You are right, I am sorry for the inconvenience! Should the question still get closed despite our comments, please ping me so that I can initiate re-opening.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Why should the question get closed?

Comment: @epsilon_delta:  Once a close vote is cast on a Question, it goes into a Close Vote review queue.   If a reviewer is not sufficiently wary, the distinction between open and non-closed may be overlooked.  So it would be an honest mistake if the Question gets closed in this way, and we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, my question was asked to review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $M \leq \mathcal{H}$ a subspace of a Hilbert space (or generally any normed space) is open, then it contains a ball around the origin $0 \in B_r(0) \subset M$, but for every (none-zero) vector $v \in \mathcal{H}$, we have
 $$ \frac{r}{2\Vert v \Vert} v \in B_r(0) \subset M $$
But M is a linear subspace so $ v \in M $. Thus the only open subspaces of $ \mathcal{H} $ are $ \mathcal{H} $ itself.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Let $N$ be a normed space and

$M \subsetneq N \tag 1$

a *proper* subspace.  Then $M$ contains no nonempty open set.  For if

$\emptyset \ne U \subset M \tag 2$

*were* open, with

$M \ni m \in U, \tag 3$

we could find $\rho > 0$ such that the open ball

$B(m, \rho) \subset U; \tag 4$

then picking any

$0 \ne v \in N \setminus M \tag 5$

the vector

$m + \alpha (v - m) \in B(m, \rho) \tag 6$

if $0 \ne \alpha \in \Bbb R$ is sufficiently small, since

$\Vert (m + \alpha (v - m)) - m \Vert = \Vert \alpha (v - m) \Vert = \vert \alpha \vert \Vert v - m \Vert < \rho \tag 7$

for

$\vert \alpha \vert < \dfrac{\rho}{\Vert v - m \Vert}; \tag 8$

but then

$m + \alpha(v - m) \in M, \tag 9$

whence

$\alpha(v - m) = m + \alpha(v - m) - m \in M, \tag{10}$

whence

$v - m \in M, \tag{11}$

whence

$v = v - m + m \in M, \tag{12}$

in contradiction to (5); therefore no $B(m, \rho)$ as in (5) can exist, and $M$ cannot be open, since it contains no open set.